# ImageView icon missing when setBackgroundColor is called

Tags: android, imageview

The image I'm setting in the app is disappearing. Here is the layout XML file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@id/txt_colorText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30.0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_colorText1"
    android:text="@string/str_textColor2"
    android:textColor="#0077dd"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img_imgColorPreview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30.0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_colorText2"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/str_imgColor" />
```

And here's the code. I do this in onTouch() method:

```
imgView_ImagePreview.setBackgroundColor(rgbCode);
```

Initially when the activity is started, ic_launcher icon is shown to the right of txt_colorText2. However on touching any part of the image, there is no content shown to the right of txt_colorText2.

I've debugged quite a lot, and haven't found the root cause. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: imgView_ImagePreview.setBackgroundColor(rgbCode); will reset your background. use imageView.setImageResource(R.color.YourColor);

Comment: in onTouch() method, I call getPixel(x,y) and get the rgbcode in int. Then I call setBackground(rgbCode) to change the background colour of the imageView.

Comment: Before using ImageView you have to learn here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing background color, you are changing the background itself. in the xml instead of setting `background`, set `src` to achieve what you want.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img_imgColorPreview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30.0dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt_colorText2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/str_imgColor" />
```

Comment: Yes, adding android:src now shows changes in the background color on onTouch(). Thanks for the help. My intention is to just preview the selected color to the right of txt_colorText2. Android logo (ic_launcher icon) is not required. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: you can set transparent as your src. try this: android:src="#00000000"

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks! But the width was too small, the image was getting previewed as a thin line. Changed layout_width to 100dip and the image is getting previewed properly now.